# Grid Items are changing places when we click on them on safari browser react material-ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am working on the React MATERIAL-UI project I am facing an issue with grid Items but this issue is only happening in the safari browser, not inside the chrome or firefox.

I have a grid, Inside the grid, I have checkboxes when I click on the checkbox then the checkboxes move from one place to another this only happens inside the safari browser.

I have uploaded a video on the youtube to explain the issue it's only a 20-second video
https://youtu.be/dGdayLJgLCE

Please watch the video till the end to see the issue.

```
<Box mt={6}>
          <Container
            maxWidth="md"
          >
            <Grid container justify="space-around" alignItems="center"  >
              {_map(_omit(activities, "other"), (selection, activity) => {
                const handleClick = experienceLevel => () =>
                  toggleExperience(experienceLevel, activity);
                return (
                  <Box m={1} key={activity}>
                    <Grid
                      item
                      container
                      // justify="left"
                      // alignItems="left"
                      justify="center"
                      alignItems="center"
                      direction="column"
                      className={classes.item}
                      wrap={"nowrap"}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    // shrink={false} 
                    >
                      <Typography variant="h5" component="h5" gutterBottom>
                        {activity}
                      </Typography>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              checked={selection === "beginner"}
                              onChange={handleClick("beginner")}
                              name="beginner"
                            // shrink={false} 
                            />
                          }
                          label="beginner"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              checked={selection === "intermediate"}
                              onChange={handleClick("intermediate")}
                              name="intermediate"
                            // shrink={false} 
                            />
                          }
                          label="intermediate"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              checked={selection === "advanced"}
                              onChange={handleClick("advanced")}
                              name="advanced"
                            // shrink={false} 
                            />
                          }
                          label="advanced"
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Grid>
                  </Box>
                );
              })}
            </Grid>
            <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
              <Box mt={3} className={classes.textFieldContainer}>
                <Typography variant="body1" component="h3" gutterBottom>
                  Describe the other activities you are interested in:
              </Typography>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  id="outlined-multiline-static"
                  multiline
                  rows="4"
                  placeholder="Let us know!"
                  variant="outlined"
                  color="secondary"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Box>
            </Grid>
          </Container>
        </Box>
        <NextBtn
          disable={_includes(activities, false)}
          href="/registration/14"
        />
```

kindly let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Try inspecting the HTML/CSS and see if anything changes when you clilck

Comment: Yes, I have inspected it these classes changes when I click on the checkbox 
MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss330 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary MuiIconButton-colorSecondary

Comment: But it works fine in chrome and firefox it does not work inside the safari.

Comment: Without more info on the html/css/scripts is impossible to know what's happening

Comment: This is my website 
http://survey.wellmode.com/

if you click on get started button then click on the
Meditation 
Hiking
Message Buttons Then click next then you will see the checkbox page The issue is on the checkbox page.

Answer (score 0):

u can try putting this in the CSS, see if this works:
-webkit-appearance: none!important;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30135049)